# Mongodb find multiple objects in nested array by providing list of ids

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the following document structure

```
{
    _id: ..., 
    topics: [ ... ], 
    posts: [ {id: 1}, {id:2}, {id: 3}]
}
```

I would like to find all posts that match specific ids. E.g

[2,3]

I have tried this:

```
db.getCollection("data")
    .find({},{
        posts: {
            $elemMatch: {
                id: {
                    $in: [2, 3]
                    } 
                }
            }
        })
```

but it only return one post

```
{
    _id: ..., 
    posts: [ {id: 3} ]
}
```

I guess another way to go would be to just return all posts and filter then manually. Which one would have a better performance?

Comment: How does your requested result look?

Comment: the `$elemMatch` will return first single matching element, for your requirement you can use [$filter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator and [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator for condition checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve it via, MongoDB, you will have to achieve it via an aggregation pipeline, because you want to filter the `posts` array, which is done via the `$filter` operator, as suggested in the comments by @turivishal. Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "posts": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$posts",
          "as": "item",
          "cond": {
            "$in": [
              "$$item.id",
              [
                1,
                2
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2q-Z8db6jxJ)

In terms of performance, usually, the filtering at the DB level is better because the operators are optimized as much as possible and also it reduces the data transferred as everything unnecessary is filtered out.

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you. I guess if you wanted to optimise the query you could add in `{ "$project": { posts: 1} }` to only return the posts field.

Comment: yes absolutely.